Debugging queue structure: "array subscript has type 'char' [-Werror=char-subscripts]"
I swiped some code from GeeksforGeeks to create a bare-bones six-element queue for an ESP32 project involving a 4x4 matrix keypad, which is supposed to trigger something else to happen if the queue matches a particular character string. After my alterations (mainly fixing the array size at 6 and merging the Dequeue() function into Enqueue() because I didn't need it separately), it reads as:
const char wildString[] = "3C3421";

// FIFO queue structure for tracking the keys
typedef struct {
    char items[6];
    char front;
    char rear;
} Queue;

void initializeQueue(Queue* q) {
    q->front = -1;
    q->rear = 0;
}

// Check if the queue is full
bool isFull(Queue* q) { return (q->rear == 6); }

// Enqueue an element
void Enqueue(Queue* q, char value) {
    if (isFull(q)) q->front++; // automatically dequeue the front element if full
    q->items[q->rear] = value;
    q->rear++;
}

This is then called in the operation loop:
// create queue to search for string "3C3421"
Queue buffer;    // checks this for if the key sequence is correct
initializeQueue(&buffer);

while(1) {
    char currentChar;
    /* snip code that decodes the keypad GPIO into currentChar */

    // write result to LCD and the buffer
    LCD_writeChar(currentChar);
    Enqueue(&buffer, currentChar);

    // beep if the buffer matches desired string
    if (strcmp(buffer.items, wildString) == 0) {
        xTaskCreate(beep, "beep", configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE, (void *)3, 5, NULL);
    }
}

But the result is that the IDE throws an error at q->items[q->rear] = value;, that array subscript has type 'char', and I'm like, well, yeah, it's supposed to because strcmp() requires one (yes, it's the one from string.h).
I've tried the suggestion from previous questions of standardizing on unsigned char, but those just end up throwing even more errors, and both the LCD library function and the string function require a char parameter anyway. A little help please?

"that array subscript has type 'char', . .  it's supposed to because strcmp() requires one" It is talking about your array subscript q->rear which is not involved with your call to strcmp() strcmp is irrelevant to this message.

It's not irrelevant: the q->rear line is acting on the array that strcmp() is receiving as a parameter.

char may be signed or unsigned depending on the implementation. The usage is legal, but risky as if your coding is dependent on the signedness and you are wrong about which one you are dealing with or the code is migrated to a compiler where the signedness is different, you can subtly mess up your array indexing. I'd just use int or short especially since you are using q->front = -1; at one point.

Well, the problem is the IDE I'm using (PlatformIO with ESP-IDF) isn't treating it as a warning, it's treating it as a build-killing error.

You are using it to index into the array. It is not ever passed to strcmp. It is not used indirectly in the call to strcmp in your posted code. It has no impact or influence on that call. Also, it can not ever be passed directly to strcmp() as it represents an index value, while strcmp parameters must be pointers to null terminated strings.

You don't have a null-terminated string in the Queue structure so you can't use strcmp() on it.  You don't limit q->front — you just increment it without wraparound.  If the code on Geeks for Geeks really looks like this, it isn't fit for the purpose you're trying to use it for.

On a different note: your items array does not appear to contain a null terminated string in your post, Perhaps you null terminate it in code not shown. Unless/until you null terminate it, you can not use it with strcmp()

Thanks for the heads-up about strcmp(), I'll figure out a different way to compare the target string to the queue.

The queue implementation on Geeks for Geeks is abysmal.  You can't add and remove elements indefinitely — the queue becomes unusable after it is first filled (until you reinitialize the queue).  You'd do best to discard the design completely and create your own.  (The test code on G4G is unbelievably trivial — it doesn't show the problems.)

The implementation notes say: Problem with Above Implementation:
The queue above works fine only for single usage. For example, lets fill the queue completely and then dequeue all the elements. Then, the front = rear - 1, which is the condition for the full queue even though the queue is empty. To resolve this, we implement the circular increment (or modular increment) for the index pointers. This kind of queue is called Circular Queue.
To know more, refer to the article Introduction to the Circular Queue.

^Noted, will rework that part tomorrow.

From a deleted comment by Jonathan Leffler:

Use unsigned char for the front and rear indexes — that will avoid the warning safely.

Nailed it. Built all the way through that time.
// FIFO queue structure for tracking the keys
typedef struct {
    char items[6];
    unsigned char front;
    unsigned char rear; 
} Queue;

Based on subsequent comments, I had to rethink my overall approach to the FIFO queue (ended up switching to a simple char array with an extra null element on the end and using a for loop to reassign the elements when a new character was added, which I could then strcmp() to the target string), but that's beyond the scope of the question.
